# How best to signal dequeue caller that call is now bridged with Twilio?

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I have a call queue that I am servicing with agents who are mobile (cell phones or at home after hours) and will get paged when a call is in the queue.  They dial the number which connects them to the queue and passes the awaiting user the url option example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
<Dial>
<Queue url="about_to_connect.xml">support</Queue>
</Dial>
</Response>
```

So my question is how best to prompt the agent that the call is bridged.  Currently they are hearing silence which is also what is going to occur if they call and someone else already grabbed the only caller in the queue and they are awaiting the timeout value.  I was hoping I could give a tone or some type of signal so they know when to answer by saying Hello this is so and so once the call is bridged to an awaiting caller.

Granted I can train the agents to know how long it should take before they connect.  I could also change the message played to the queued caller to announce themselves but that seems odd when this isn't a conference call but a 2 party bridged call.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here,

It looks like the problem you're having could be solved by adding in some more [Twiml verbs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=june2015&utm_campaign=stackathon) to alert the caller. You can do this with the [Say](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say&utm_medium=june2015&utm_campaign=stackathon) command by having a robot voice read text over the phone line, or by using the [Play](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play&utm_medium=june2015&utm_campaign=stackathon) command to play a prerecorded sound.

An example of this using some raw Twiml could look like:

```
<Response>
    <Say>You are now being bridged to a caller</Say>
    <Dial>
        <Queue url="about_to_connect.xml">support</Queue>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

If you need any more help with the Queue verb, you can check out our [Call Queue How-To](https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/callqueue&utm_medium=june2015&utm_campaign=stackathon), which includes example code and Twiml.